# Power systems unclear voltages

Tags: electrical-engineering, power, electrical, power-engineering, power-transmission

I was looking at this problem:

"A balanced delta connected impedance load with (12+j9)Ω per phase is supplied by a balanced three-phase 60 Hz, 208-V source "

I do not wish to ask for help at solving this, rather, I want to know how to interpret the "208 V source" statement. If someone gives me that statement I will immediately think it means
$$ V_{an} = 208 V \angle 0º $$
and we can just get $V_{bn}$ and $V_{cn}$ by adding $\angle +240º$ and $\angle +120º$ respectively.

However I have seen people interpreting this as $ V_{LL} = 208 V$, what reason do they have to conclude it refers to LL and not LN, the problem does not sate it.

Comment: Normally, unspecified voltage three-phase voltage is considered to be LL.  But this depends on individual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the problem specifies the load is "delta connected". There is no neutral connection to measure phase voltage ($V_{LN}$) against.

Also note the supply frequency is 60 Hz. 208 V is a common [line](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/alternating-current/chpt-10/three-phase-y-delta-configurations/) voltage ($V_{LL}$) in the US (which uses a 60 Hz supply), with corresponding phase voltage of 120 V. You are using a US text (Sarma *et al*, from another post) so you can expect to see examples of US practice.

So the problem is asking about $V_{LL} = 208 V\;$.